# Opening a rowset for "Sheet1$" failed. Check that the object exists in the database

Tags: sql-server, ssis, import-from-excel, sql-job

I am attempting to create a SSIS Package in SQL Server Management Studio.  The package simply imports data from an Excel File on a corporate shared drive and into a database table.  Upon completion of the SSIS package, I select to "Run Package Immediately" and to save the package.  The SSIS package runs & saves successfully; all employee records are inserted into the table (That's GREAT!). Now, here is where the issue comes into play.  I want to execute that SSIS package as part of a job.  But, when running the job and attempting to execute the SSIS package, I am receiving the following error message:

> Opening a rowset for "Sheet1$" failed. Check that the object exists in the database.
> ...returned validation status "VS_ISBROKEN".

Why does the SSIS package work/run successfully when it's first created, but then proceeds to fail when it's being executed from a job?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/74PQe.png)

I don't believe this is an account/access problem - only for one small reason. We technically have two Excel Spreadsheets & SSIS packages which do the same thing. The Excel files are different sets of data, but they're stored in the same corporate network drive/folder and both get uploaded to the same database (different tables however).  Excel File 'A' is not experiencing this problem, but Excel File 'B' is.  And both of the jobs are setup to run using the same account.  Also, one other small/side note - if I perform a "Save As" on Excel File 'A' and recreate the SSIS package/job, then that new file (Excel file 'C') will experience the same issue we're facing as Excel File 'B'. So, why would the job work on an 'original file' but then proceeds to fail once I perform a "save as" and try it on the new file?

Comment: So where it says `Executed as user ...` is that your account or something else's? Likely it's the account under which SSIS is executing, or maybe a proxy account, but does that account have access to the share where the Excel document resides?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning is probably correct but if it does not help, try opening the package in Visual Studio (you can add packages from the server if you don't have it saved as a file) . From there you should be able to see exactly what the problem is as the the connection manager will probably have an error.

Comment: Please see my edit in the post above since I wasn't able to add it to the comments section.  Also, I do have visual studio installed, but I am not proficient with it.  Could you explain where I would go within the tool to troubleshoot/find the exact issue?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

In my case , we were dynamically generating the filename. The Source file name was not matching the filename generated. So correcting the filename worked.

Comment: Add some more detail about the solution. Did you experienced the same issue with SSIS and face the same error? The question seems to be related with sheets inside the workbook, not to the workbook name itself.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the file connection and set the property delay validation true.